# Determine which array is lengthier JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, max, min

**SORRY I HAD TO CHANGE THE QUESTION I SCREWED UP. The purpose is to use the Math.max function to determine the lengthiest array. I needed to add an additional parameter to make it practical because everyone was using > instead of Math.max. I was writing this example to fast and didn't think of that.**

Is there an easier way to do this? The purpose is to be able to take many arguments (more than two) and find out which has a larger length. I'd like it to be dynamic, so It seems I need to give a name property to each array before passing them in. This is the only way to find an arrays name right?

```
var arrayLogA = [8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 0, 9, 4];
arrayLogA.name = 'arrayLogA';

var arrayLogB = [1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2]
arrayLogB.name = 'arrayLogB';

var arrayLogC = [1, 6, 9, 3, 3, 7, 3, 2]
arrayLogC.name = 'arrayLogC';

function returnLargestArray(a, b, C) {

    ...
}

returnLargestArray(arrayLogA, arrayLogB);
```

ok, this is more practical, if I'm going to explain the Math.max function and also return the largest, I'm going to have to rethink the function. Sorry for any confusion. I typically write good questions but I think I rushed this one. Very sorry.

I may need to pass additional parameters in. SO maybe I should not have used a, b, c as the arguments.

Comment: Adding a `.name` property isn't really valid array syntax - JavaScript either has ordered Arrays or Objects with properties - not associative arrays

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @tymeJV it's perfectly valid. In JavaScript Arrays _are_ objects.

Comment: Why does this need to be wrapped in a function? Can't you just use `arrayLogA.length < arrayLogB.length`?

Comment: I need to be able to run two arrays through a function that returns the winners name.

Comment: @Oleg - Maybe valid isn't the word I'm looking for...but adding a property to an array like that is definitely....not right. Or maybe it is and I've just been living a lie.

Comment: How else would you know it's name?

Comment: Why do you need to know the winner's name? Can you just know what the winner is?

Comment: Array's don't have built-in names in Javascript, rather variables refer to arrays... you should be able to just use the winning array. Still there's nothing preventing you from setting a name property on the array itself if you want (though this will be independent of whichever variables happen to reference it)

Comment: @tymeJV look no further than jQuery collections! Now, the matter of _right_ or not is, I suppose, up to the reader, but it is certainly _done_.

Comment: I guess it just bothers me when adding a key/val to an array - this will mess with array like functions (looping) :\

Comment: Math.max and Math.min are more practical to use when you are comparing more than two numbers, otherwise you would just use the comparison operators.

Comment: Yeah I think I will work that into the example. show one and then show the more practical way of doing things. That's actually a good point.

Comment: Will your returnLargestArray function always take the same number of inputs?  Or is that unknown?

Comment: I would say that you should be able to pass many in. more than two.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm confused. I was trying to make a better example of the Math.max function and it got out of control

Comment: So, you're determined to use Math.max, huh?

Comment: The entire point was to use Math.max to determine which arrays were longer. I admit I started with two arrays, But my example was very easy to change to more than two. I'm stepping through learning Math Functions. It's not about this one problem but more the bigger picture of what Im trying to teach. This is about example 10 in a tutorial that builds on previously learned concepts. As I get further down the chain things start to get hairy or not practical so I have to change things a bit to make sense. I am sorry if it caused some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this might be a little less than ideal, and certainly feels a bit weird, but you could do something like this.

```
var arrayLogA = [8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 0, 9, 4];
arrayLogA.name = 'arrayLogA';

var arrayLogB = [1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2];
arrayLogB.name = 'arrayLogB';

var arrayLogC = [1, 6, 9, 3, 3, 7, 3, 2];
arrayLogC.name = 'arrayLogC';
...

var arrayLogN = [ ... ];
arrayLogN.name = 'arrayLogN';

function returnLargestArray(/* some unknown number of arrays */) {
  var lengths = [];

  // store lengths of each array
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    lengths.push(arguments[i].length);
  }

  // use Math.max to get biggest length
  var largest = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);

  // use indexOf to get the index of biggest length
  var indexOfLargest = lengths.indexOf(largest);

  // use the indexOfLargest to return that value from arguments
  return arguments[indexOfLargest].name;
}

returnLargestArray(arrayLogA, arrayLogB, arrayLogC, ..., arrayLogN);
```

Using this method will return to you the lengthiest array passed in to the function, without requiring you to name each array.

Just a quick note: this function invokes Math.max.apply rather than just Math.max because Math.max expects a number of inputs, rather than just one array that we're trying to find the maximum within.  To make Math.max work on an array, we have to use Math.max.apply.

I hope this does what you want!

Edit:  Added name properties to the arrays in order to return name at end of function.

Comment: I'm playing with this.

Comment: In that case, assuming your arrays are already names, in the end you can return arguments[indexOfLargest].name.

Comment: Just edited that in to the answer.  It looks a little weird to add properties like 'name' to an array.  Using an object would make it look more like proper javascript, but you could do it either way.

Comment: Yep, I have both ways written out one using object and the other using arrays. Can you think of any reason not to use the additional name property on the array?

Comment: I almost had exactly what you had here, but I forgot to put the .name after arguments[indexOfLargest] lol Not sure if I will use it in my example for the reason you stated. I just thought the easiest way to get the name was to add it as a property.

Comment: Yeah, you could definitely do that.  I mean, the only reason I wouldn't do it that way is kinda silly... Since people don't usually add properties to arrays, I would be afraid that someone looking at my code would think I had no idea what I was doing if I used an array with a name property rather than an object.

Comment: I can understand, and I do agree it's a bit silly. But the way I see it, everything in JavaScript is an object so, I didn't think twice about doing it and to tell you the truth I'm surprised that it's not done more often. I feel like prototyping might be another option or as someone else did, they made an object and attached a name property then attached an array to the object. Seems the same to me, but whatever. I'm not skurred of someone calling me out though. Maybe I'm the genius? Probably not. lol

Comment: Heheh, yeah.  I can understand doing it either way.  Actually, now that I'm thinking about it a bit more, I'm wondering how different browsers would treat extra properties on arrays.  I mean, if you want to iterate over everything in it, you would have to use a for-in loop, which, again, feels a bit weird because depending on the browser you might get extra unexpected properties which could throw off your app. (I just tested it in chrome, and it only lists the indices and name property, but I don't know how other browsers would react)

Answer (score 2):

```
function returnLargestArray(a,b){
  if(!a || typeof a.length =="undefined" ||
     !b || typeof b.length =="undefined") {return;}
  if(a.length==b.length){/*return some value of your choosing*/}
  return a.length>b.length?a:b;
}
returnLargestArray([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]);
```

But beware of caveats for non "simple" arrays.

- Non-array objects with a length property
- Arrays which have had indexes explicitly set, will be counted based on their max index, not the number of "used" indexes

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Also, I'd argue it's quite safe to do just `a.length === undefined`.

Comment: In this case yes, but if the reader of the answer doesn't understand why it's safe, it could be misapplied elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  (I haven't tested it yet, but it makes sense!)

```
function returnLargestArray(a, b) {

    if (a.length > b.length) {
        return console.log("winner: "+ a.name);
    } else {
        return console.log("winner: "+ b.name);
    }
}
```

If they're the same length that will fail, but you get the idea.

Comment: Why do you `return console.log`??

Comment: I just used that code from the question. I assume that's what he wants (for whatever reason).  Returning a.name or b.name seems simpler to me.

Comment: @BrettFromLA The OP surely doesn't want that because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Oleg Good point. TBH, I was rushing because I wanted to have the first answer, and I knew this was a simple question that would have several responses. That's why I copied his code -- for speed. Bad habit!!

Comment: Im only returning console because I was experimenting with it. I was trying to use Math.min to segway into math functions in an example. SO far everyone has crapped the Math.max function lol SHould have said that. ALso the solution needs to be readable to a very basic or novice JavaSCript developer or student.

Comment: There was several other steps that led to this example can't print it all out. but basically we ended up with two arrays that we needed to determine which was larger. It doesn't have to be the most compact or shortest code, yet a good example of how to use a Math.max function to determine the winner.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
if (a.length > b.length) {
  console.log("winner: "+ a.name);
  return a;
else {
  console.log("winner: "+ b.name);
  return b;
}
```

or if you want it to be really short:

```
return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
```

As a side note, your logic could use a little work. Right now it returns the output from `console.log`, which is `undefined`. Returning the array makes more sense, and makes more sense from the name of your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function returnLargestArray(a, b) {
    return 'winner is ' + (a.length == b.length ? 'nobody' : (a.length > b.length ? a : b).name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different structure in your code. Looks like you need objects with two properties: A name and an array of data.

```
var logA = {
  name: "logA",
  array: [8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 0, 9, 4]
};

var logB = {
  name: "logB",
  array: [1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2]
};
```

Then define a function operating on such objects:

```
function largestLog( a, b ) {
    if ( a.array.length > b.array.length ) {
       return a;
    }
    else {
       return b;
    }
}
```

And then you can call the function, get the object with largest array, and print its name to console:

```
var l = largestLog( logA, logB );
console.log( l.name );
```

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstances you would probably check the length of the arrays and then return the one that satisfied the logic (larger or smaller) then work with that object.

The reassignment of a and b, to arrayA and arrayB seems to have no merit, other that to give a semantic answer. You may as well use those var assignments as strings as it would make more sense in the context your are demonstrating.

```
var arrayLogA = [8, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 0, 9, 4];
var arrayLogB = [1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2]
function returnLargestArray(a, b) {
    var a = a.length,
        b = b.length,
        winner = 'arrayA';
    if(a < b && a !== b) {
        winner = 'arrayB';
    } else {
      winner = 'none';
    }
    return winner;
}
returnLargestArray(arrayLogA, arrayLogB);
```

`Math.max()` is probably surplus to requirements, I wouldn't imagine it has any speed advantages over normal operators `[=!<>]` seeing as you are bringing another object in to play `Math` and accessing a function of that object.

The way I have been taught is (in this binary scenario [true, false] [a or b] etc) is to set a return value at the top of the function. This way everyone who reads can easily see what the functions purpose is, then use your logic to switch that state.

So if winner = a; you test is b larger than a, if it is, set winner = b. Saves a lot of code and should be more efficient.

Comment: This was closest to what I was trying to do my question got out of hand and I'm thinking about deleting it because I confused everyone. Very sorry. ANy possibility you could take a look at the rephrased question.